# how to use pushFrontViewController of SWRevealViewController with swift

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have discover that the pushFrontViewController function in SWReveal.

I have added the UIViewController in the storyboard's Contact.[image]
And I am trying covert to swift, but it do not work.
Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     //CODE TO BE RUN ON CELL TOUCH
        var newFrontController: UIViewController
        let selectedItemMenu = arrayOfSlider[indexPath.row]

        var revealController  = SWRevealViewController()
        var contact_nav = ContactViewController()
        newFrontController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:contact_nav) 
        revealController.pushFrontViewController(newFrontController , animated:true)
}
```

Is there anything that I am wrong?

Comment: what the error u faced

Comment: There is no error in the coding, but the view cannot be changed pragmatically. And i added a new picture for more detail

Comment: can u send your project for my mail Id karthik.saral@gmail.com

Comment: I gave up. the swreveal is hard to do the dynamic navigation. do you navigate it successfully?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After having a depth research, I just need some simple code to solve this case which is at the below:

```
            self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true)
            let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerStoryBoardID[indexPath.row]) as! UIViewController
            self.revealViewController().setFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

SWRevealViewControllor is not that much hard. you should follow [this example](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/). I think its a perfect example you can try. It may help you !

Comment: Thank you very much for your helping, but I think that it is not suitable for me. The reason is that the user can edit the menu bar from the DB which means that I need to do it dynamically. After this 2 months, I have depth research on SWReveal that there is a simple code to do it `self.revealViewController().setFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)`. Anyway, thank you for your example.